# What software to use to build interactive tutorials?

Tags: images, flash

I am looking for a software using which I could build tutorials of enterprise applications.

I have seen Adobe Captivate, which to a very far extent fulfills my requirements. But, I do not have any expertise on that tool and the tutorials provided by Adobe are not that interesting.

Can you please suggest such tool and if I can find any tutorials related to it?

Comment: Your description is too broad. You need to specify your requirements.